# Odp.Net - permanent change notification

Tags: oracle, odp.net

Each time when my application is starting I have to create new registration for change notification. Does exists any way to register permanent ? I would like to create one registration for all time. After restart server or application all should work without again registration.

Comment: It is similar problem to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542807/oracle-data-change-notification-timeout-and-workflow second point. After I kill server (sometimes it happens when restart conmputer) all my notifications are down, deleted from database even when TImeout is set to 0. Why?